# Using IOUtils in Android to convert Uri/Url to String

Tags: android

I've researched and created the following code in my android studio project

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView notificationsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notifications_text);
    Uri one = Uri.parse("http://textfiles.com/adventure/221baker.txt");
    Uri two = Uri.parse("http://textfiles.com/adventure/adventureland.txt");
    Uri three = Uri.parse("http://textfiles.com/adventure/adventur.txt");

    notificationOne = IOUtils.toString(one);
    notificationTwo = IOUtils.toString(two);
    notificationThree = IOUtils.toString(three);
    notificationsText.setText(notificationOne);

}
```

It so far does not convert the Uri to string but instead states it cannot resolve the method .toString(android.net.Uri)

I've imported IOUtils`import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;`
and enabled internet access in my manifest file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`.

So, how can I resolve it, or, is there an easier way to convert a Url to a string?

You might want to check the content of the Urls before answering.

This toString method is different than the one used to convert normally in android without IOUtils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`IOUtils.toString()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.net.URI)) takes a [`java.net.URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) as its argument. You are passing it an `android.net.Uri`.

When calling `IOUtils.toString()`, you should also make sure to pass the content encoding as the second argument.

Comment: How do I pass it as the other version?

Comment: I added the `java.net.URI` documentation link in the answer. You can do `URI one = new URI("http://textfiles.com/adventure/221baker.txt");` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was first using the wrong version 1.3.2

Then I found this gradle config fixed it

```
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
```